# Pass C array into function as individual values

Tags: c, arrays

I want to pass array of hex or decimal values into function, without relying on escape sequences inside ascii string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char one[] = "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF";
char two[] = { 0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF };

int main()
{
    puts(one);
    puts(two);
    puts("\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF");
    puts((char *){0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF}); // I guess that's not how it works
}
```

I've seen syntax like this somewhere, but cannot track down portion of documentation describing correct use of it.

When I pass syntax like this into "mikroC Pro for AVR" it flips out and drop "invalid expression". Nonetheless something("\xAB\xCD"); pass perfectly fine. Which part of standard describes use of it ? microC is not C99 compliant(avr-gcc get it, but generate warnings).

Comment: You want to `put` a string but pretend it isn't a string?  Why?

Comment: Is it `puts` or this `func` you are calling?

Comment: I also can't see `char one = "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF";` compiling in most compilers. I'd expect `char *one = "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF";`

Comment: Note that `puts(two);` causes undefined behavior, as there is no terminating NUL character.  The same the happens with a compound literal without a NUL.

Comment: Another problem not mentioned yet is that all those initializers are out of range for `char` on common systems (the actual range is `-0x80` through `0x7F`)

Answer (score -1):

Someone point me to refer "compound literals" in answer but quickly got deleted(why?), which led me to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html looks like it only C99/C++ compliant, which explains bogus use of it.

Also it demands size declaration of     subsequent literal inside type declaration of casting:

```
puts((char [4]){0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF}); // valid, but only in C99 and later or C++
```

Comment: You still are overlooking the null termination requirement